# What's "conditional" about a conditionally convergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

This is something that's bothered me ever since I learned about infinite series in high school. It seems to me that the series *is* convergent, and the only claim being made is that the *different* series created by taking the absolute value of each term is divergent. But that's not a condition on the convergence of the original series itself; it still converges. The other series might be related, but it in no way affects the original series; it's completely irrelevant to adding up the terms of the original series.

Is there some deeper math thing here that I'm missing, or is the terminology just a historical accident?

If it helps to provide some context to my understanding of mathematical topics, I'm an engineer, not a mathematician.

Comment: The series **is** convergent. However, if a sequence it absolutely convergent then it can be rearranged at will and will still converge. If it is only conditionally convergent the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem has something to say. Being able to rearrange is often very useful.

Comment: In other words, what it is conditional on is "the order you add them up". Some people might say "well yeah, the order is part of the definition of a series", but there is an intuition (that _is_ valid for finite sums) that the order you choose to add things up shouldn't affect the final total you get. But that's not true for conditionally convergent series. Hence the name, which I've always taken as a "Beware of Series" sign, posted to remind you that things can go wrong if you don't take care when dealing with this one.

Comment: +1 for @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC comment. I like "Beware of Series" phrase.